# Does free revving diesel engine near redline for 2-3 seconds harm it

Tags: engine, diesel, rpm, rev-limiter

What happened is I accidently pressed the accelerator and rpm shot to 4800-4900 rpm in neutral. The engine was fully warmed-up. Redline of the engine starts from 5000rpm and revv-limiter kicks in at around 5200 rpm. Does it damage the engine or Am I being overly paranoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being overly paranoid. While this action isn't *good* for the engine, it won't harm it. There's a redline for a reason, that being an engine speed you should not exceed. You weren't exceeding this level, so there should be no issue. Engines are designed to take abuse over the long haul. Manufacturers build in a margin of error to help protect the engine from people doing stupid things to them. Your running it up to just below the redline for a few seconds isn't going to cause any issues.

Comment: Well said.  Interestingly, connecting rod bearing load exponentiates with respect to RPM, and engine load is a much lesser factor.  I didn't beleive this until I saw the math.  The stress from reciprocation is phenomenal, right around TDC and BDC where the piston acceleration change is at maximum.  The combustion event is a much milder compressive force on the rod bearings.  Bottom line is try not to over-rev, ever.  #NeverEverOverRevHer